# Add a bunch of non source code files to a vcxproj

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I need to add a folder containing lots of Qml files into a visual studio project. (The folder has subfolders and I want to add every thing to the project)

I tried to drag & drop from Explorer (and with the "Show all Files" way) to add the containing folder but this ways work only for source files (.cpp, .h, ...)

Do you know how to add easly lots of non-source-code files into a visual studio project ?

Comment: What is the build system supposed to do with these files?

Comment: Just right click `Add Folder` then `Add existing files`

Comment: @HansPassant do post-build event action when the solution is built and the qml files are modified

Comment: @NathanKoop It's does not work for folders

Comment: I have always just created the folder through VS (usually one at a time with several files), but if you're adding lots of folders I can see this being time consuming.

Comment: Does the folder you want to add have subfolders?

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry if my english bother you. The post-build event does not modifies then, the events must be "fired" with the files are modified before building the solution

Comment: @JimRhodes Yes, and I want to add every files contained

Comment: As far as I know, you would have to do `Add->Existing Item...` for each subfolder and just select all the files. You can maintain the folder structure in the project by adding filters.